# Pycharm no pregunta por el input

Tags: python, pycharm

Recién estoy empezando a programar y no entiendo por que al compilar solo pone

> "Process finished with exit code 0"

en vez de preguntarle al usuario por su nombre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Please translate your question into spanish because you're at SO en español

Comment: Pycharm no pregunta por el input. Recien estoy empezando a programar y no entiendo por que al compilar solo pone "Process finished with exit code 0" en vez de preguntarle al usuario por su nombre.

Comment: por favor edita tu pregunta y traducela, no lo hagas en la zona de comentarios

Comment: hola, disculpa. Como la edito?

Comment: Justo debajo de tu pregunta hay un enlace que dice editar

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu carpeta raíz tienes dos archivos llamados **suma**, pero uno es de extensión `.py`, entonces al momento de llamar el archivo por consola, estás llamando al archivo que no tiene la extensión antes mencionada

Lo que tienes:

```
C:\Python38-32\python.exe [tus directorios]\python\suma
```

Cuando debería ser:

```
C:\Python38-32\python.exe [tus directorios]\python\suma.py
```

---

En resumen, estás llamando al archivo incorrecto, ya que donde está tu código es en `suma.py`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!

Comment: Me pasó un montón de veces cuando estaba aprendiendo hahah suerte! que nada te frene :)